# constructor saying method can't be duplicated

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class IronMan {
private double totalTime = 3.7;

public IronMan() {
    System.out.println("First Constructor running");
}

public IronMan() {
    System.out.println("Second Constructor running");
}

}

public class Marathon {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    IronMan person1 = new IronMan();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(
            "A triathlon is a challenging task. This program will allow you to know which is the perfect course for you.");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("What is your age?");
    int age = scan.nextInt();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("What is your time for one mile, in minutes?(ex: 5.3 or 6.2");
    double time = scan.nextDouble();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("How much is your budget?");
    double money = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(money);
    if (money <= 100) {
        System.out.println("You can't afford entrance!");
    } else if (money > 100) {
        if (age < 10) {
            System.out.println("You don't qualify!");
        } else {
            if (time > 10) {
                System.out.println("You do not qualify");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Good! you do qualify");
                IronMan person2 = new IronMan();
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

I am a bit new to the concept of constructors. I was trying to create the constructor IronMan; however, Eclipse gives me an error message under the word IronMan. It says that "Duplicate method IronMan() in type IronMan". I don't understand why it says the method is duplicated, since it is supposed to be a constructor.

Comment: Well you can have only one constrictor with same set of arguments, similar as functions.

Answer (score 1):

You have two constructors with the same signature (both without parameters). This is not allowed, since there's nothing that distinguishes between the two.

When you write `IronMan person1 = new IronMan();`, you have no way of specifying which of these two constructors should be invoked, so it's not allowed to have both.

Comment: What if they are both with parameters? Would that be allowed?

Comment: @Pablo If they had a different signature (i.e. parameter lists of different length or different types of parameters), it would be allowed.

Comment: public IronMan() {
  System.out.println("First Constructor running");
 }

 public IronMan(double money) {
  System.out.println("Second Constructor running");
 }  Would that work?

Comment: @Pablo Yes, it would.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors allow you how to create an instance of an object. You can create ironMan `IronMan ironMan = new IronMan()` without set ironMan name and age, `IronMan ironMan = new IronMan("Brad")` this means your ironMan name is brad. `IronMan ironMan = new IronMan("Brad", 29)` means your ironman name is Brad and his age is 29. if you delete `IronMan()` constructor, you will enforce to the developer to enter ironMan name(with `IronMan(String name)`) or name and age (with `IronMan(String name, int age)`) while creating an instance of IronMan.

```
public class IronMan {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public IronMan() {
    }

    public IronMan(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public IronMan(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```